# How to make angular wait for response of DWR Call?

Tags: angularjs, promise, dwr

```
function with DWR Call  
self.getUsers = function()
        {
            console.log("Get User called");
             userProjectDWRManager.getAllUsers(function(list){
            console.log(list);
           return list;
        });
      }


  var list = self.getUsers();
console.log(list) //undefined
```

I tried promise concept but I don't understand exactly how to apply it with DWR exactly.

Edit:

The whole scenario is that I am in

```
 $transitions.onStart({
      }, function(trans) {
// get list here from DWR call
    if(list.length==0)
                {
                    event.preventDefaults();
                    $state.go('register',{});
                }

      }
```

In this function I want to get the list and wait for the list to return before going to the next state. But it always goes to the next state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass a reference to a callback function into promise function to execute after promise resolved.

```
self.getUsers = function(callback)
        {
            console.log("Get User called");
             userProjectDWRManager.getAllUsers(function(list){
             callback(list);//executes the callback function
        });
      }


self.getUsers(showList); //pass reference to callbak function

function showList(list){
  console.log(list);
}
```

for your updated question

```
        $transitions.onStart({
    }, function(trans) {
        // get list here from DWR call
        userProjectDWRManager.getAllUsers(function(list){
            if(list.length==0)
            {
                event.preventDefaults();
                $state.go('register',{});
            }


            else
                console.log('list is Not empty');
        });
    });
```

Comment: I tried the code above.
Actually I want to wait till I have the list. But it continues execution without waiting for list to return. It never enters the showList function.

Comment: @VishveshBhandari execute caback function where the promise is resolved

Comment: The whole scenario is that I am in transition:$transitions.onStart({
      }, function(trans) {}

In this function I want to get the list and wait for the list to return before going to the next state. But it always goes to the next state.

Comment: add the code which going to next state inside the callback function

Comment: I added full code here. It will go to the next state without going into the callback function.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: This is the problem.
In your updated answer it does not wait for server to get the list , and hence never goes in if -else condition.
It goes to the next state.
Also event.preventDefault() does not work.

Comment: the function `userProjectDWRManager.getAllUsers` how it works?

Comment: It justs returns an array of users like a normal java function.

Comment: If I can just prevent it from going to the next state then your method of passing call back will work.
But I can't seem to find any way to stop the normal transition with hooks.
Earlier with routechangestart event.preventDefault() use to work perfectly.
But with transition hooks there must be some new function which I cannot find.